# Screenshot utility

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, 22.04, snap, screenshot

Seems like the default screenshot utility went through some features overhaul but have become a royal pain in the neck and significantly increased the clicks and typing required. Here are few details:

1. To find the utility, need to click "activities" and type "screenshot" as the utility cannot be added to favorites.
2. After taking a snapshot it automatically copies the content to clipboard, there is no option to save the file within the utitlity.
3. So need to open pinta or some other utility and then go through few more clicks to save the screenshot.

Is there a better way or more efficient alternative?

Comment: 1. Not true in Gnome 42 and newer. Simply press the "Print Screen" button. You don't need to click "activities" nor search for "screenshot"

Comment: 2 and 3. Not true in Gnome 42 and newer. Screenshots are on the clipboard AND saved to ~/Pictures/Screenshots. Both. Every screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To find the utility, need to click "activities" and type "screenshot" as the utility cannot be added to favorites.

There is a much shorter and more efficient way to summon the tool: shortcut keys. The forthcoming Gnome desktop will add a button in the Power menu for quick mouse access.

> After taking a snapshot it automatically copies the content to clipboard, there is no option to save the file within the utitlity.

The behavior has changed to become (even) more efficient. A screenshot always is saved both to the clipboard and to a file under ~/Pictures/Screenshots.

- This avoids the mental overhead of having to decide ahead where you want to save the screenshot
- It allows to reduce shortcut keys to only three, one to summon the tool for interactive use (PrtScr), one for the full screen (Shift+PrtScr) and one for a window (Alt+PrtScr). A huge improvement to an already efficient tool, but that is only my opinion.

> So need to open pinta or some other utility and then go through few more clicks to save the screenshot.

Feel free anytime to use any other screenshot tool. You can also install the old default tool (as shown in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1432115/558158) of Bernt Ribbun), `gnome-screenshot` if you prefer the old behavior.

Comment: Yes these suggestions help and did not know about the saved files under ~/Pictures/screenshots which pretty much solves the problem at hand! Thanks a lot!

Comment: And you guys are right, the new upgrade is indeed more efficient!!

Comment: If this helped you, then please "accept" the question: click the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

There is: use `gnome-screenshot`. I have modified the keyboard shortcuts to run `gnome-screenshot`, `gnome-screenshot -a` and `gnome-screenshot -w`, for fullscreen, selectable area and window, respectively.
You can also specify which directory the shots are stored in. Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: you can also  run it as a shortcut key. you can also delay it, whilst you go to what you want captured.

gnome-screenshot -d 10